# SQL Server 2012 : commit doesn't match to begin tran inside stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

I wrote this stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 Express.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Dictionaries].[InsertCountry]
(@p_countryName nvarchar(128)
 , @ret_countryId int OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TransactionName VARCHAR(20) = 'INST_COUNTRY';

    BEGIN TRANSACTION @TransactionName;

IF len(@p_countryName) <= 3
BEGIN
        SET @ret_countryId = null
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION @TransactionName;
END

INSERT INTO [Dictionaries].[CountryDetails] (name)
VALUES (@p_countryName);    

SET @ret_countryId = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO [Dictionaries].[Places] (name, Discriminator , CountryDetails_Id, RegionDetails_Id, CityDetails_Id)
VALUES (@p_countryName, 'Country' , @ret_countryId, null, null);

COMMIT TRANSACTION @TransactionName;
END
```

I use this method in this way, but I get message

> The COMMIT TRANSACTION request has no corresponding BEGIN TRANSACTION.

Code:

```
declare @ret int = null
EXEC [Dictionaries].[InsertCountry] 'us', @ret output
```

What is wrong in this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you rollback, then you commit. This is a bug. Probably, you meant to return after the rollback.

Comment: After rollback, I want to escape from stored procedure. Just add RETURN keyword after rollback?

Comment: Yes, just use normal control flow. Make sure not to execute the commit. Do that any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of stored procedure templates / boilerplate provided by Microsoft: [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)(example B or C; for non-nested transactions) or [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188378.aspx)(for nested transactions). Also, you could use RAISERROR to generate an exception if some conditions aren't meet.

Example (based on the last template - [nested transactions]):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.objects
           WHERE name = N'dbo.Country_Insert')
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.Country_Insert;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Country_Insert
(
    @p_countryName nvarchar(128)
    ,@ret_countryId int OUTPUT
)
AS
    -- Detect whether the procedure was called
    -- from an active transaction and save
    -- that for later use.
    -- In the procedure, @TranCounter = 0
    -- means there was no active transaction
    -- and the procedure started one.
    -- @TranCounter > 0 means an active
    -- transaction was started before the 
    -- procedure was called.
    DECLARE @TranCounter INT;
    SET @TranCounter = @@TRANCOUNT;
    IF @TranCounter > 0
        -- Procedure called when there is
        -- an active transaction.
        -- Create a savepoint to be able
        -- to roll back only the work done
        -- in the procedure if there is an
        -- error.
        SAVE TRANSACTION ProcedureSave;
    ELSE
        -- Procedure must start its own
        -- transaction.
        BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    -- Modify database.
    BEGIN TRY

    -- Custom source code
IF len(@p_countryName) <= 3
BEGIN
        SET @ret_countryId = null
        RAISERROR('Wrong contry name', 16, 1);
END

INSERT INTO [Dictionaries].[CountryDetails] (name)
VALUES (@p_countryName);    

SET @ret_countryId = SCOPE_IDENTITY() -- @@IDENTITY isn't safe

INSERT INTO [Dictionaries].[Places] (name, Discriminator , CountryDetails_Id, RegionDetails_Id, CityDetails_Id)
VALUES (@p_countryName, 'Country' , @ret_countryId, null, null);
    -- End of Custom source code

        -- Get here if no errors; must commit
        -- any transaction started in the
        -- procedure, but not commit a transaction
        -- started before the transaction was called.
        IF @TranCounter = 0
            -- @TranCounter = 0 means no transaction was
            -- started before the procedure was called.
            -- The procedure must commit the transaction
            -- it started.
            COMMIT TRANSACTION;
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        -- An error occurred; must determine
        -- which type of rollback will roll
        -- back only the work done in the
        -- procedure.
        IF @TranCounter = 0
            -- Transaction started in procedure.
            -- Roll back complete transaction.
            ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        ELSE
            -- Transaction started before procedure
            -- called, do not roll back modifications
            -- made before the procedure was called.
            IF XACT_STATE() <> -1
                -- If the transaction is still valid, just
                -- roll back to the savepoint set at the
                -- start of the stored procedure.
                ROLLBACK TRANSACTION ProcedureSave;
                -- If the transaction is uncommitable, a
                -- rollback to the savepoint is not allowed
                -- because the savepoint rollback writes to
                -- the log. Just return to the caller, which
                -- should roll back the outer transaction.

        -- After the appropriate rollback, echo error
        -- information to the caller.
        DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
        DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

        SELECT @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE();
        SELECT @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY();
        SELECT @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

        RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, -- Message text.
                   @ErrorSeverity, -- Severity.
                   @ErrorState -- State.
                   );
    END CATCH
GO
```

Note: As you can see, I've used SCOPE_IDENTITY() instead of @@IDENTITY. The reason is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172121%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).